# How do I pin a particular MySQL version to avoid unnecessary upgrades?

Tags: apt, aptitude, mysql, pinning

I'm running a MySQL server, and want to keep it up to date with regular apt-upgrades. I don't want this to cause MySQL to upgrade unless I'm doing it during scheduled downtime! How do I alter my apt-preferences so that this won't happen?

I've tried adding this to a file as /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-mysql

```
Package: mysql-client-5.1
Pin: version 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.7
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: mysql-client-core-5.1
Pin: version 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.7
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: mysql-common
Pin: version 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.7
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: mysql-server
Pin: version 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.7
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: mysql-server-5.1
Pin: version 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.7
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: mysql-server-core-5.1
Pin: version 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.7
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

That then states the packages are pinned with "apt-cache policy" outputting:

```
... all package sources here
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/universe Packages
     release v=10.04,o=Ubuntu,a=lucid-security,n=lucid,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/restricted Packages
     release v=10.04,o=Ubuntu,a=lucid-security,n=lucid,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin security.ubuntu.com
... etc
Pinned packages:
     mysql-server -> 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.7
     mysql-server-core-5.1 -> 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.7
     mysql-client-core-5.1 -> 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.7
     mysql-common -> 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.7
     mysql-server-5.1 -> 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.7
     mysql-client-5.1 -> 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.7
```

However... running aptitude safe-upgrade just updated MySQL... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, why are you running automatic updates at all? shouldn't you schedule your updates with either cron or do them manually?

Comment: I didn't say I was running *automatic* updates. I said *regular* updates. I want to separate out run of the mill updates from ones that really need scheduled downtime.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prevent the upgrade of a package, then pinning is not the way to go. What you need is called holding, and you can find out how to do it [on this page in the Ubuntu online help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Introduction%20to%20Holding%20Packages)

Answer (score 2):

Holding does appear to be the way to go, though I'm not quite sure on the difference between dpkg and aptitude holds.

At any rate - the following script is doing what I want and excluding a list of packages from an aptitude safe-upgrade.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Stop the mysql packages from upgrading!
# Must run as root! Check presence of the packages-hold.log file to avoid running repeatedly.

PACKAGES="mysql-client-5.1 mysql-client-core-5.1 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1 linux-image-server linux-image-2.6.32-28-server"

for PACKAGE in $PACKAGES;
do
    /bin/echo $PACKAGE hold | /usr/bin/dpkg --set-selections
done
/usr/bin/aptitude hold $PACKAGES
echo $PACKAGES > /var/log/packages-hold.log
```

Without doing the aptitude hold line, aptitude would still try to update packages marked with the `dpkg --set-selections` command and *I think* the opposite also applies.

FYI - this also blocks the kernel image from updating all the time. I'm only interested in that update if it's for high priority security reasons as it always comes with a reboot attached.