# Kubuntu 16.04 failed upgrade (problem with xserver-xorg-video-all?)

Tags: upgrade, xorg, kubuntu, 15.10, 16.04

I'm trying to upgrade my Kubuntu Wily 15.10 computer but it fails.

I'm doing this:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop
```

This is what I get:

```
Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This can be caused by: 
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.
```

I found this on `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log`:

```
2016-04-29 10:29:09,024 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of key deps for 'kubuntu-desktop')
2016-04-29 10:29:16,112 DEBUG Installing 'xserver-xorg-video-all' (Distro KeepInstalledPkgs rule)
2016-04-29 10:29:16,559 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'
2016-04-29 10:29:16,560 DEBUG abort called
2016-04-29 10:29:16,576 DEBUG openCache()
2016-04-29 10:29:16,576 DEBUG failed to SystemUnLock() (E:Not locked) 
2016-04-29 10:29:20,464 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 78719
2016-04-29 10:29:20,464 DEBUG enabling apt cron job
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I could solved. I follow the advice from this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/367329/483417

What I did was:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-all
sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop
```

I waited for the upgrade ends and restarted the computer. After that, Kubuntu started with no problems. The graphics were configured too. I think that is because I have a nvidia graphic card and the driver upgrade reinstalled everything again, even `xserver-xorg-video-all`.

Finally, my Kubuntu is Xenial :-)

Comment: Had the same problem while trying to upgarde from 18.04 -> 20.04 and your post solved it.
I replaced
'sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop' with 'sudo do-release-upgrade -d'