# upgrading to ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.04, 13.10

I'm trying to upgrade from ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 .
but i have xorg-edgers drivers installed ,so I get error when I upgrade.
same errors as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360293/upgrading-13-04-to-13-10-could-not-calculate-the-upgrade)
so i tried the command :

> grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log

and got a list of packages as [here](http://i40.tinypic.com/s3pw69.jpg)

how do I remove those packages ?

Answer (score 0):

You can revert to the original xorg packages by purging the PPA:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
$ sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers
```

This should remove the edgers PPA, reverting xorg packages to the mainline versions and allowing you to upgrade (via downgrading ;)).