# Problem while upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 version

Tags: 13.04, upgrade

Hello i was trying to update my ubuntu version then i get this problem.

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

This can be caused by:
 * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

Can somebody help me?

Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not calculate the upgrade, what happened?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360293/could-not-calculate-the-upgrade-what-happened)

Answer (score 0):

As i am also one of the unfortunates to have constant upgrade problems in the previous years, i really warmly recommend doing a clean install from a USB stick or a CD. Backup your files, and do a clean install.

Cheers.