# Can't upgrade from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: upgrade

I do `sudo do-release-upgrade`, and I got an error message like this one.

> An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
>
> This can be caused by:
>
> - Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
> - Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
> - Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

How I can solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not calculate the upgrade, what happened?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360293/could-not-calculate-the-upgrade-what-happened)

Answer (score 0):

Most times it's because of the last point listed: You've got some PPA's enabled which can't be upgraded.

Disable all PPA's you've installed manually and run the upgrade. After upgrading, re-enable them.

This is most easily done via the "Software & Updates" utility.