# Can not Upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, 14.04

When I try to upgrade from Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 to Ubuntu 14.04, the upgrade application fails with the following message:

```
Could not calculate the upgrade. 
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.`
```

Here is the complete log:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 13.10 \n \l
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This can be caused by: 
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
```

Am I missing something? or it is just a bug?

UPDATE:
I analyzed the log file and found that `do-release-upgrade` is complaining about some obsolete packages.

```
$ cat /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log | grep Obsolete
2014-04-28 09:16:23,678 DEBUG Obsolete: flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound:i386 (..)
```

After removing those packages, I was able to proceed with the upgrade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Look in `/var/log` for release-upgrader log files that will have more details.
2. The error message explains:

`This can be caused by: 
    ...
    * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu`

So, do you have any software from PPAs installed, or have you edited any of the default sources?  If so, that's probably the problem.  Disable any PPAs or other third-party repos and try again.  If it still doesn't work you might need to actually uninstall some packages or replace them with versions from the official repos.

Comment: should have looked harder before asking the question

Comment: If you solved the problem, please explain how.

Comment: For me, it was necessary to re-install (sudo apt-get install --reinstall ...) the few "broken" packages, which I found using DaShaun's solution from here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/360293/could-not-calculate-the-upgrade-what-happened

Comment: I had to `sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1` which I found mentioned in `/var/log/dist-upgrade/20140724-1521/main.log`: `ERROR: Dist-upgrade failed: 'The package 'postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1' is marked for removal but it is in the removal blacklist.'`

Answer (score 1):

I've been following this thread since 14.04 came out and finally resolved my issues: it turned out that (for me) the error was caused by having Cinnamon installed.

I used Synaptic to search for and remove all of Cinnamon as well as Nemo and Muffin (two utilities that are part of Cinnamon). The regular distro upgrade command

```
      sudo do-release-upgrade
```

then worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

When I updated to kubuntu 15.04, I had the same problem due to `php` , `MSQL`, `xserver-xorg-video` packages which were broken.

You can view broken libs by:

```
grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log
```

To remove xserver-xorg-video use below command:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-*
```

I also removed some conflicting `mysql` and `php` libs using synaptic package manager.

Please do backup of databse before remove mysql,php libraries

Thanks