# Upgrade fails. How should I interpret the apt.log?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

when I run

$ sudo do-release-upgrade

I get an error "could not calculate the upgrade"

I see from this link that I am supposed to run this command [Could not calculate the upgrade, what happened?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360293/could-not-calculate-the-upgrade-what-happened)

But how should I interpret the apt.log? How do I fix this?

```
$ grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log
Broken xz-utils:amd64 Conflicts on xz-lzma [ amd64 ] < 5.1.1alpha+20110809-3 > ( utils )
Broken libhdf5-7:amd64 Conflicts on libhdf5-1.8 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libhdf5-7:amd64 Conflicts on libhdf5-1.8.4 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libhdf5-7:amd64 Conflicts on libhdf5-serial-1.8.4 [ amd64 ] < 1.8.4-patch1-3ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libnetcdfc7:amd64 Breaks on libnetcdf6 [ amd64 ] < 1:4.1.1-6 > ( libs ) (< 1:4.1.1-7~)
Broken libsnmp-base:amd64 Breaks on libsnmp15 [ amd64 ] < 5.4.3~dfsg-2.4ubuntu1.2 > ( libs ) (< 5.7.2~dfsg-5)
Broken libgdal1:amd64 Depends on libhdf5-serial-1.8.4 [ amd64 ] < 1.8.4-patch1-3ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libgdal1:amd64 Depends on libhdf5-1.8.4 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libgdal1:amd64 Depends on libnetcdf6 [ amd64 ] < 1:4.1.1-6 > ( libs )
Broken postgis:amd64 Depends on libgdal1 [ amd64 ] < 1.9.0-3.1~pgdg12.4+1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.9.0)
Broken postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1:amd64 Depends on libgdal1 [ amd64 ] < 1.9.0-3.1~pgdg12.4+1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.9.0)
Broken libxerces-c-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libxerces-c2-dev [ amd64 ] < 2.8.0+deb1-2build3 -> 2.8.0+deb1-3build1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libperl5.14:amd64 Depends on perl-base [ amd64 ] < 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.4 -> 5.18.2-2ubuntu1 > ( perl ) (= 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.4)
Broken libgdal1-1.7.0:amd64 Depends on libhdf5-serial-1.8.4 [ amd64 ] < 1.8.4-patch1-3ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libgdal1-1.7.0:amd64 Depends on libhdf5-1.8.4 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libgdal1-1.7.0:amd64 Depends on libnetcdf6 [ amd64 ] < 1:4.1.1-6 > ( libs )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can, go through that list of packages and `sudo apt-get purge` them. Then try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

again.

Also, you can now install Ubuntu 14.04 and you are given the option to upgrade an existing Ubuntu installation that allows you to **keep** the data in your home folder during the installation process. *Always back up your data first* of course. You may not be able to keep all the applications you have installed through apt-get and software center but at least you get to keep your downloads, saved data and some of your settings.

Alternatively, you could otherwise choose the option "something else" set your mount point at " / " and make sure to NOT have the option to FORMAT selected . . . again, **do not select to format**.

Installing without formatting allows you to overwrite the program files and directories while keeping your home folder intact thus preserving personal data and settings. Again, always make a backup.