# Could not calculate upgrade 14.04 -> 16.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.4 and just tried unsuccessfully to upgrade to 16.04.1. 14.04 has been reliable, but 16.04 is being less than hospitable!

I `sudo do-release-upgrade`, and it falls over in exactly the way described in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360293/could-not-calculate-the-upgrade-what-happened) (dating from the days of 13.10), complete with unhelpfully vague error message.

I then [`grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log`](http://pastebin.com/Nz8WFYiv) to find broken packages, as the top-rated answer suggests, and generate a list of over 900 broken packages!

Other information I have available:

- `main.log`
- `sudo dpkg -l | grep -w "rc"`
- `sudo rename 's/\.list$/.list.disable/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list && sudo aptitude update && aptitude search '?narrow(?installed, !?archive(trusty))'`

Mostly these are a bit of a wall of text, hence attempting to use pastebin -- stymied by lack of reputation, apparently. I can post anything needed as a comment.

Before I consider installing 16.04.1 over the top of 14.04, is there anything I should try in order to get the release-upgrade method to work? Or is my system now sufficiently riddled with third-party stuff (particularly, things installed to get other bits of software working / deal with inadequate driver support etc.) that I should bite the bullet and do a clean install? -- or junk it and stick with 14.04...

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. The linked thread suggests manually removing the broken packages, but, given that there's so many of them, I wonder if I'll be able to upgrade anything at all after doing that...

Comment: Same issue. About 300 broken packages for me