# Can't calculate error when upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, upgrade, 20.04, do-release-upgrade

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my laptop and was trying to upgrade to 20.04. After disabling PPA sources and running the upgrade tool, I receive the "Could not calculate the upgrade" error.

The logs for Broken packages from `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` are available [here](https://pastebin.com/BcLT7KV0). There seems to be +200 packages with conflicts including very important ones like python, so removing all of them as proposed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/360448/202705) is not an option. I have already tried `apt remove` and `apt autoremove` and removing 3rd party apt sources and the whole nine yards.

Considering that I haven't used this laptop for too long, it is very strange that the automatic update is impossible. Are there any other ways to force the upgrade using the `do-release-upgrade` tool?

Comment: This might help: update upgrade 18.04 first.

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE thanks for the reply, I suppose you mean 19.04. how can I do that with `do-release-upgrade`?

Comment: I think there is no 19.04, you go directly to 20.04.  The command is `update-manager -c` (in 20.04, I hope it also works in 18.04).  You may also reinstall completely but you have a greater chance to wipe out your data.  Upgrading saves about 3 GB compared to complete install.  20.10 is also available with some improvements but no long term support.

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE I have already run update upgrade dist-upgrade, any other way to avoid complete reinstall?

Comment: As I wrote, you can start from scratch. Backup as much as you can before. Take 20.04 for the long term support.

Comment: Erratum : I withdraw that upgrading saves download  bit count compared to full install.