# Could not calculate the upgrade, what happened? 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: package-management, upgrade, ppa

I'm trying to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04, but toward the end of the "Setting new software channels" stage I received the following error message.

```
Could not calculate the upgrade
An unresolvable problem occurred while
calculating the upgrade.  
This was likely caused by:  
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu  
 
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge
package to remove software from a
Launchpad PPA and try the upgrade again. 
If none of this applies, then please report
this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core'
in a terminal. If you want to investigate
this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade'
will contain details about the upgrade.
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'."
```

I've already looked at the most relevant post I could find, [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360293/could-not-calculate-the-upgrade-what-happened) Following their guidance, as well as the instruction from the error, I looked at both main.log, to find where the process failed and at apt.log (with grep Broken). As far as the main.log goes, the relevant broken packages I saw were colord and ubuntu-desktop, which, as far as I could tell are ubuntu packages—and so, therefore probably not the problem?? As for apt.log, I'm seeing dozens of broken packages (if you can make heads or tails of the long list, they're [here](https://listed.to/p/qT0zbzTQ9b).

From what I understand, I need to remove broken non-ubuntu packages in order to proceed with the upgrade by this route. Is that right? If so, do I just have to look up each broken package to figure out how it got installed? That seems like a ton of work, is there some shortcut? Or is there some other way I could upgrade without sorting this out, without just going for a clean upgrade?

Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question with the full output of both `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. Use code block formatting by putting three backticks on a new line before the paste and three more backticks on a new line after your paste. Do not manipulate any text inside the paste. This adds unnecessary ambiguity and makes the information difficult to parse. Don't upload pictures of text. Your system needs to be up-to-date, you need to disable 3rd party sources, and your package manager must be error free before attempting a release upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Unfortunately or fortunately—I was able to advance past this problem by initiating the release upgrade through terminal...where I am now stuck with an entirely different problem—unmet dependency errors.

Comment: We need the same exact information on that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to my sloppiness, I found myself in continued issues, as described in the comments above. What I ultimately did was setup a USB stick with 20.04, do a clean install from that, and migrate everything from my Aptik backup. I just do that in the first place next time if I encounter any friction with an upgrade.