# Error while upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, updates

This is the error when running `sudo do-release-upgrade`

```
Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

 This was likely caused by:
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove the software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again.

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.
```

When I ran this command:

```
grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log
```

and it showed all these broken packages

```
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons:amd64 < 20.04.0-3~ubuntu20.04.6 @ii mK > (< 21.04)
Broken gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 Breaks on libmutter-6-0:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii mK > (< 3.37)
Broken libpeas-1.0-0:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken fuse3:amd64 Breaks on fuse:amd64 < 2.9.9-3 -> 2.9.9-5ubuntu3 @ii umU >
Broken python3-uno:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken libayatana-appindicator3-1:amd64 Conflicts on libappindicator3-1:amd64 < 12.10.1+20.04.20200408.1-0ubuntu1 -> 12.10.1+20.10.20200706.1-0ubuntu1 @ii umU >
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken gdb:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken libtss2-mu0:amd64 Breaks on libtss2-esys0:amd64 < 2.3.2-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii mK > (< 3.0.1-2)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken python3-dev:amd64 Depends on python3.10-dev:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.6-1~)
Broken libgupnp-av-1.0-3:amd64 Breaks on libgupnp-av-1.0-2:amd64 < 0.12.11-2 @ii mK > (< 0.14)
Broken libpython3-dev:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10-dev:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.6-1~)
Broken gir1.2-unity-7.0:amd64 Conflicts on gir1.2-unity-5.0:amd64 < 7.1.4+19.04.20190319-0ubuntu3 @ii mK >
Broken python3-venv:amd64 Depends on python3.10-venv:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.6-1~)
Broken sssd-ad:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.15.9+dfsg)
Broken sssd-ipa:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.15.9+dfsg)
Broken libgupnp-dlna-2.0-4:amd64 Breaks on libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3:amd64 < 0.10.5-4 @ii mK > (< 0.12)
Broken libgc1:amd64 Conflicts on libgc1c2:amd64 < 1:7.6.4-0.4ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libosdcpu3.4.4:amd64 Breaks on libosdcpu3.4.0:amd64 < 3.4.0-6build1 @ii mK > (< 3.4.3-2)
Broken blender:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken thonny:amd64 Depends on python3-venv:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umR >
Broken sssd-ad-common:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.15.9+dfsg)
Broken libwacom2:amd64 Depends on libwacom-common:amd64 < 1.3-2ubuntu3 -> 2.2.0-1 @ii umU > (= 1.3-2ubuntu3)
Broken libgcc1:amd64 Depends on gcc-10-base:amd64 < 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 -> 10.4.0-4ubuntu1~22.04 @ii umU > (= 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04)
Broken python3.8-venv:amd64 Depends on python3.8-distutils:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libsemanage1:amd64 Depends on libsemanage-common:amd64 < 3.0-1build2 -> 3.3-1build2 @ii umU > (= 3.0-1build2)
Broken gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 Depends on libmutter-6-0:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii mR > (= 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
Broken gvfs-bin:amd64 Depends on gvfs-common:amd64 < 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1 -> 1.48.2-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2)
Broken sssd:amd64 Depends on sssd-ad:amd64 < none | 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2 @un uH > (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2)
Broken vlc-plugin-samba:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on libwbclient0:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 -> 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umU > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 | 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-talloc:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 | 2.3.3-2build1 @ii umR > (>= 2.3.1~)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 -> 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umU > (= 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 -> 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umU > (< 3.9)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 -> 2.3.3-2build1 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 | 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken gvfs-backends:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.12.0+dfsg)
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5 @ii umR >
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on libpython3.10:amd64 < none | 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 @un uH > (>= 3.10.0)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on libwbclient0:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 -> 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umU > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 | 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-talloc:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 | 2.3.3-2build1 @ii umR > (>= 2.3.1~)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 -> 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umU > (= 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 -> 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umU > (< 3.9)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 -> 2.3.3-2build1 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 | 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.450.2 | 1.481 @ii umR >
Broken gnome-remote-desktop:amd64 Breaks on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 | 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5 @ii umH Ib > (< 1:41.4-1ubuntu10)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libsmbclient:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libwacom2:amd64 < 1.3-2ubuntu3 @ii gR > (>= 1.1)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center-data:amd64 < 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu4 -> 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5 @ii umU > (< 1:3.37)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 | 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-talloc:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 | 2.3.3-2build1 @ii umR > (>= 2.3.1~)
Broken libwacom2:amd64 Depends on libwacom-common:amd64 < 1.3-2ubuntu3 -> 2.2.0-1 @ii umU > (= 1.3-2ubuntu3)
Broken libwacom9:amd64 Depends on libwacom-common:amd64 < 1.3-2ubuntu3 | 2.2.0-1 @ii umH > (= 2.2.0-1)
Broken libmutter-10-0:amd64 Depends on libwacom9:amd64 < none | 2.2.0-1 @un umH > (>= 2.0.0)
Broken gir1.2-mutter-10:amd64 Depends on libmutter-10-0:amd64 < none | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @un umH > (= 42.5-0ubuntu1)
Broken libwacom-bin:amd64 Depends on libwacom9:amd64 < none | 2.2.0-1 @un umH > (>= 2.0.0)
Broken libinput-bin:amd64 Depends on libwacom9:amd64 < none | 2.2.0-1 @un umH > (>= 2.0.0)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 -> 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umU > (= 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 -> 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umU > (< 3.9)
Broken python3-markupsafe:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken duplicity:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken python3-protobuf:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken python3-psutil:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken python3-wrapt:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken python3-brlapi:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken python3-reportlab-accel:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 -> 2.3.3-2build1 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken python3-sss:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken python3-tk:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10.5-0~)
Broken python3-mypy:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken python3-cffi-backend:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken mypy:amd64 Depends on python3-mypy:amd64 < 0.761-1build1 | 0.942-1ubuntu1 @ii ugH > (>= 0.942-1ubuntu1)
Broken python3-numpy:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken python3-simplejson:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 | 3.10.6-1~22.04 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.10~)
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on libmutter-10-0:amd64 < none | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @un umH > (>= 42~beta)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on gir1.2-mutter-10:amd64 < none | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @un umH > (>= 42.0)
Broken gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 Depends on libwacom9:amd64 < none | 2.2.0-1 @un umH > (>= 2.0.0)
Broken ubuntu-session:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 < 3.36.1-0ubuntu1.1 | 42.1-1ubuntu2.1 @ii umR > (>= 3.37.0)
Broken libinput10:amd64 Depends on libwacom9:amd64 < none | 2.2.0-1 @un umH > (>= 2.0.0)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 < 3.36.1-0ubuntu1.1 | 42.1-1ubuntu2.1 @ii umR > (>= 3.29)
Broken gdm3:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 < 3.36.1-0ubuntu1.1 | 42.1-1ubuntu2.1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.37.0)
Broken update-manager:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken update-notifier:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken python3-reportlab:amd64 Depends on python3-reportlab-accel:amd64 < 3.5.34-1ubuntu1 | 3.6.8-1 @ii umH Ib > (>= 3.6.8-1)
Broken gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (< 43)
Broken gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (>= 3.33)
Broken xserver-xorg-input-libinput:amd64 Depends on libinput10:amd64 < 1.15.5-1ubuntu0.3 | 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1 @ii umH > (>= 1.19.1)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 -> 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umU > (= 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)
Broken chrome-gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (>= 3.38)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 -> 2.3.3-2build1 @ii umU > (= 2.3.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken sssd-common:amd64 Depends on python3-sss:amd64 < none | 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2 @un ugH >
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on python3-ldb:amd64 < 2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 | 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.1 @ii umR > (>= 2:2.1.0)
Broken gnome-shell-extension-prefs:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (= 42.5-0ubuntu1)
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gdm3:amd64 < 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 | 42.0-1ubuntu7 @ii umR >
Broken gnome-shell-extensions:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (< 43~)
Broken sssd-krb5-common:amd64 Depends on sssd-common:amd64 < none | 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2 @un ugH > (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2)
Broken sssd-proxy:amd64 Depends on sssd-common:amd64 < none | 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2 @un ugH > (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2)
Broken sssd-krb5:amd64 Depends on sssd-common:amd64 < none | 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2 @un ugH > (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2)
Broken sssd-ldap:amd64 Depends on sssd-common:amd64 < none | 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2 @un ugH > (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2)
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gdm3:amd64 < 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 | 42.0-1ubuntu7 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 < 33.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42-2~fakesync1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 < none | 43-2ubuntu1 @un umH >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 < 68ubuntu1~20.04.1 | 72~ubuntu5.22.04.1 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.450.2 | 1.481 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-session:amd64 < 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 | 42.0-1ubuntu2 @ii umR >
Broken gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umH Ib > (< 40)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii gR > (>= 3.36.0)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-common:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 -> 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on mutter:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (>= 3.36.0)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on libmutter-6-0:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii gR > (>= 3.36.0)
Broken gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < 3.36.1-0ubuntu1.1 -> 42.1-1ubuntu2.1 @ii umU > (= 3.36.1-0ubuntu1.1)
Broken ubuntu-session:amd64 Depends on gnome-session-bin:amd64 < 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 -> 42.0-1ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.37)
Broken ubuntu-session:amd64 Depends on gnome-session-common:amd64 < 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 -> 42.0-1ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 3.36.0-2ubuntu1)
Broken libgjs0g:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umH IPb > (< 3.38.6)
Broken libgweather-3-16:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umH IPb > (< 40.4-1~)
Broken gir1.2-gweather-3.0:amd64 Depends on libgweather-3-16:amd64 < 3.36.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1 | 40.0-5build1 @ii umH > (>= 40.0)
Broken gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-3.0:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umH IPb > (< 42~alpha)
Broken yaru-theme-gnome-shell:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 | 42.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umH IPb > (< 42~)
Broken gnome-startup-applications:amd64 Depends on gnome-session-bin:amd64 < 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 | 42.0-1ubuntu2 @ii umH > (>= 42.0-1ubuntu2)
Broken gjs:amd64 Depends on libgjs0g:amd64 < 1.64.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.01 | 1.72.2-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (= 1.72.2-0ubuntu1)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 | 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umR > (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)
Broken ubuntu-settings:amd64 Depends on gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 < 3.36.0-1ubuntu1 | 42.0-1ubuntu1 @ii umH > (>= 40)
Broken eog:amd64 Depends on gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 < 3.36.0-1ubuntu1 | 42.0-1ubuntu1 @ii umH > (>= 42~beta)
Broken gnome-calendar:amd64 Depends on libgweather-3-16:amd64 < 3.36.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1 | 40.0-5build1 @ii umH > (>= 40.0)
```

above mentioned command is copied from this link:

[Could not calculate the upgrade, what happened?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360293/could-not-calculate-the-upgrade-what-happened)

Comment: What happened after you purged the ppas and tried again?