# do-release-upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 is aborting at calculating changes stage

Tags: updates, update-manager

Logs of failure:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                                                                                                                                    
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,251 kB]                                                                                                                                                           
Fetched 1,252 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                          
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done                                                                          
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [6,612 B]                                                                                       
Fetched 1,215 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                          
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Checking for installed snaps

Calculating snap size requirements

Updating repository information

Third party sources disabled 

Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can 
re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool 
or your package manager. 

To continue please press [ENTER]                                      
Get:69 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [6,808 B]                                                                                          
Fetched 59.7 MB in 6s (2,909 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                      

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

There is no issue in apt.log

main.log output

```
2023-06-23 10:13:05,145 DEBUG Free space on /: 4048220160
2023-06-23 10:13:05,145 DEBUG Dir /usr mounted on /
2023-06-23 10:13:05,145 DEBUG Dir /var mounted on /
2023-06-23 10:13:05,145 DEBUG Dir /boot mounted on /
2023-06-23 10:13:05,146 DEBUG Dir /var/cache/apt/archives mounted on /
2023-06-23 10:13:05,146 DEBUG Dir /tmp mounted on /
2023-06-23 10:13:05,146 DEBUG Free space on /home: 59700662272
2023-06-23 10:13:05,146 DEBUG Dir /tmp mounted on /
2023-06-23 10:13:05,146 DEBUG fs_free contains: '{'/tmp': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f9378d16780>, '/var': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f9378d16780>, '/home': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f9378d168d0>, '/boot': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f9378d16780>, '/usr': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f9378d16780>, '/var/cache/apt/archives': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f9378d16780>, '/': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f9378d16780>}'
2023-06-23 10:13:06,678 DEBUG dir '/var/cache/apt/archives' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f9378d16780>' (4048220160.000000)
2023-06-23 10:13:06,678 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f9378d16780>' (4048220160.000000)
2023-06-23 10:13:06,678 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '52428800' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f9378d16780>' (4048220160.000000)
2023-06-23 10:13:06,678 DEBUG dir '/boot' needs '66868533.9' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f9378d16780>' (3995791360.000000)
2023-06-23 10:13:06,678 DEBUG dir '/tmp' needs '5242880' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f9378d16780>' (3928922826.100000)
2023-06-23 10:13:06,679 DEBUG dir '/' needs '10485760' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f9378d16780>' (3923679946.100000)
2023-06-23 10:13:06,679 DEBUG dir '/tmp' needs '0.0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f9378d16780>' (3913194186.100000)
2023-06-23 10:13:06,679 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '0.0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f9378d16780>' (3913194186.100000)
2023-06-23 10:13:06,679 DEBUG Found writable ESP /dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
2023-06-23 10:13:06,692 DEBUG found components: {'bionic-updates': {'main', 'restricted', 'universe', 'multiverse'}, 'bionic-security': {'main', 'restricted', 'universe', 'multiverse'}, 'bionic': {'universe', 'restricted', 'main', 'multiverse'}}
2023-06-23 10:13:06,692 DEBUG abort called
2023-06-23 10:13:06,700 DEBUG openCache()
2023-06-23 10:13:09,653 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 93393
2023-06-23 10:13:09,653 DEBUG enabling apt cron job
```

No error message found hence not able to figure the reason of failure? Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably because both 16.04 and 18.04 are beyond EOL. See [this related answer for more info](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/167115).

Comment: You may get a package not found error when trying to install `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core` and if this happens, just install `update-manager-core` instead: `sudo apt-get install update-manager-core`

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support

Comment: see this answers https://askubuntu.com/questions/360293/could-not-calculate-the-upgrade-what-happened

Comment: None of the above suggestion worked.

Comment: If none of them worked, then it's time to back up your data and then clean-install a supported release of Ubuntu. Your output suggests that your 16.04 system has not received security updates in years, so the system should be wiped anyway.